# Swift UITableView with multiple columns

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a UITableView with multiple columns to display standings for football leagues. I have already tried creating it using multiple UITableViews (shown in the screenshot below).

Has anyone got suggestions for another approach?

[UITableView Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suEep.png)

[UITableview in the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq3wo.png)

Comment: Consider SwiftUI which is much more versatile than UIKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this problem would be to have a model like:

```
struct TeamScoring {
    let teamName: String
    let scores: [String]
}
```

Then you create a `TeamScoring` for each team.

Regarding the view, only a single `UITableView` is needed. You have to create a `UITableViewCell` that contains labels for all the values.

In the implementation of the following delegate method, for each index you have to pass a model to the corresponding cell:

```
func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> UITableViewCell
```